# what might be causing the error "Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State."?

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, signalr

I try to connect SignalR hub from ASP.NET backend app with my Vue 3 frontend app on localhost. My backend works on https://localhost:7001/ and frontend on https://localhost:3000/. The first problem was CORS configuration,i fixed it and now I have new type of error. My code is super simple, because i used manuals. What might be causing the error?

Thats my CORS configuration:

```
 builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => 
            {
                builder.AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins(
                    "https://localhost:3000/","https://localhost:7001/","/","localhost")
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
  configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseRouting();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
```

My vite config - i use it to proxy requests from localhost:3000 to localhost:7001

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => ['md-linedivider'].includes(tag),
        },
      },
    }),
    vuetify(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:7001',
        secure: false,
        ws: false,
      },
      '/ws': {
        target: 'http://localhost:7001',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: true,
      },
    },

    https: {
      cert: readFileSync(certFilePath),
      key: readFileSync(keyFilePath),
    },
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
})
```

My Vue component

```
`<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
    <button @click="sendMessage">Send</button>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id">{{ message.text }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr'
export default {
  setup() {
    const message = ref('')
    const messages = ref([])

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:3000/ws/chat')
      .build()

    connection.on('Receive', (message) => {
      messages.value.push({ id: Date.now(), text: message })
    })

    onMounted(async () => {
      try {
        await connection.start()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    })

    const sendMessage = () => {
      if (message.value) {
        connection.invoke('Send', message.value)
        message.value = ''
      }
    }
    return {
      message,
      messages,
      sendMessage,
    }
  },
}
</script>


And SignalR Hub:


`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatHubSpace
{
   
        public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Send(string message)
        {
            await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("Receive", message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
  const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:7001/chat',{
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
      .build()
```

This worked